# php str_replace returns empty string

Tags: php, str-replace

```
<?php

$html = '<form id="form1" name="f1" action="/jk" dummy';

$html = str_replace(
    '<form id="form1" name="f1"',
    '<form id="form1" name="f1" xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    $html);

echo $html;
```

Why the result is empty?

I'm using PHP 5.3.27 (cli)

Thanks.

Comment: [Runs fine](http://codepad.org/tzi5IKIL). Are you sure you don't have any special characters (such as new lines) within the HTML? Also, if this comes from a webpage, you should consider DOM or methods of parsing.

Comment: Works fine here. Are you viewing this in a browser? Try 'view source', in case the browser is hiding the tag from view.

Comment: @MarcB I swear that's probably what the OP is experiencing, good call.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's exactly the problem, I'm testing with Chrome browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$html = '<form id="form1" name="f1" action="/jk" dummy';
$html = str_replace(
    '<form id="form1" name="f1"',
    '<form id="form1" name="f1" xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    $html);

echo highlight_string($html, true);
```

another way to show is:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method,

```
<?php
echo 'hello<br>';
$html = "abcde<br>";
echo $html;
$a = substr_replace($html,
    'xyzhi',
    0);

echo $a;
?>
```

Str_replace will need word which you want to replace from the string.I hope this may work.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at *source code* <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> you will find it is replaced successfully there, but Why cannot see it on the browser page? because the browser thinks of it as a tag.
So to show it on the browser page we can use *htmlentities()*:

```php
$html = '<form id="form1" name="f1" action="/jk" dummy';
$html = str_replace(
    '<form id="form1" name="f1"',
    '<form id="form1" name="f1" xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    $html);

echo htmlentities($html);
```

*Output*:

```html
<form id="form1" name="f1" xxxxxxxxxxxxx action="/jk" dummy
```